# removing files that have extension .bin then printing bye

Tags: shell, unix

```
filename=file.bin
extension=$(echo ${filename}|awk -F\. '{print $2}')
if [ ${extension} == "bin" ]; then
   rm *.extenstion
fi
```

would something like this work how do I delete all files that have the same extention in a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extract the extension yourself, this is what globbing is for. Simply do:

```
rm *.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Or recursively `find ./ -name "*.bin" -exec rm -f {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from globbing, this is also doable with `find`.

```
find -type f -name "*.bin" -exec rm {} \;
```

Or more efficiently, with newer version of `find`:

```
find -type f -name "*.bin" -exec rm {} +
```

which is equivalent to

```
find -type f -name "*.bin" | xargs rm
```

Note: by default, `find` will do it recursively.